# Performance comparison: one argument or a list of arguments?

Tags: tcl

I am defining a new TCL command whose implementation is C++. The command is to query a data stream and the syntax is something like this:

```
mycmd  <arg1>  <arg2> ...
```

The idea is this command takes a list of arguments and returns a list which has the corresponding data for each argument.

My colleague commented that it is best just to use a single argument and when multi values are needed, just call the command multiple times.

There are some other discussions, but one thing we cannot agree with each other is, the performance.

I think my version, list of argument should be quicker because when we want multi arguments, it is one time cost going through TCL interpreter.

His comment is new to me -

> 1. function implementation is cached
> 2. accessing TCL function is quicker than accessing TCL data

Is this reasoning sound?

Comment: You think? Why don't you measure?

Comment: run [benchmark](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/bench.html) when in doubt

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Tcl_EvalObjv` to invoke the command, you won't go through the Tcl interpreter. The cost will be one hash-table lookup (or less, if you reuse the `Tcl_Obj*` containing the command name) and then you'll be in the implementation of the command. Otherwise, *constructing* a list `Tcl_Obj*` (e.g., with `Tcl_NewListObj`) and then calling `Tcl_EvalObj` is nearly as cheap, as that's a special case because the list construction code is guaranteed to produce lists that are also substitution-free commands.
Building a normal string and passing that through `Tcl_Eval` (or `Tcl_EvalObj`) is significantly slower, as that has to be parsed. (OTOH, passing the *same* `Tcl_Obj*` through `Tcl_EvalObj` multiple times in a row will be faster as it will be compiled internally to bytecode.)

Accessing into values (i.e., into `Tcl_Obj*` references) is pretty fast, *provided* the internal representation of those values matches the type that the access function requires. If there's a mismatch, an internal type conversion function may be called and they're often relatively expensive. To understand internal representations, here's a few for you to think about:

- `string` — array of unicode characters
- `integer` — a C `long` (except when you spill over into arbitrary precision work)
- `list` — array of `Tcl_Obj*` references
- `dict` — hash table that maps `Tcl_Obj*` to `Tcl_Obj*`
- `script` — bytecoded version
- `command` — pointer to the implementation function

OK, those aren't the exact types (there's often other bookkeeping data too) but they're what you should think of as the model.

As to “which is fastest”, the only sane way to answer the question is to try it and see which is fastest for real: the answer will depend on too many factors for anyone without the actual code to predict it. If you're calling from Tcl, the `time` command is perfect for this sort of performance analysis work (it is what it is designed for). If you're calling from C or C++, use that language's performance measurement idioms (which I don't know, but would search Stack Overflow for).

Myself? I advise writing the API to be as *clear and clean* as possible. Describe the actual operations, and don't distort everything to try to squeeze an extra 0.01% of performance out.

Comment: The problem with “is the reasoning sound?” is that the statements are true but not necessarily relevant to performance.